# SELECT from different table and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, socialengine, mariasql

The original query is

```
SELECT user_id, user_location, displayname FROM engine4_users WHERE user_location IS NOT NULL
```

Which prints the user_id, user_location and displayname,

```
Ex:
1 30,32 demo
2 30,31 demo
3 33,32 demo
```

but now i need ot get the user picture from another table and i have this,

```
SELECT  s.storage_path as url FROM engine4_storage_files as s
LEFT JOIN  engine4_users as u ON s.file_id = u.photo_id
```

Which prints the URL only

What I need is to add that url to the first query

Comment: just add the missing fields from the first query, to the second query?

Comment: they are in different tables

Comment: you're using both tables in the second query? just change `SELECT s.storage_path` to `SElECT u.*, s.storage_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_location, u.displayname, s.storage_path as url 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files s
ON s.file_id = u.photo_id 
WHERE u.user_location IS NOT NULL
```

**Extended by request in comments:**

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_location, u.displayname, w.value as about, s.storage_path as url 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_user_fields_values w 
ON w.item_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files s
ON s.file_id = u.photo_id 
WHERE u.user_location IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It have this error "Unknown column 's.storage_path' in 'field list'".

I think this is working right;  am i right?

`SELECT u.user_id, u.user_location, u.displayname, storage_path as url 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files 
ON file_id = u.photo_id 
WHERE u.user_location IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Oh i am sorry that I have forgot to give an alias to engine4_storage_files. I  have edited my answer so it should be workable now :)

Comment: What if I would like to add this

`SELECT w.value as about
FROM engine4_user_fields_values w
WHERE w.field_id = 13`

Comment: Any relation between this field and engine4_users? Is it always have data or it could be NULL? What does this field used for?

Comment: It pulls a short description about the user, the relation is user_id = item_id

Comment: It works nice, with filtering now,
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_location, u.displayname, w.value as about, s.storage_path as url 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_user_fields_values w 
ON w.item_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files s
ON s.file_id = u.photo_id 
WHERE u.user_location IS NOT NULL AND w.field_id = 13